# How to install Zend Opcache and Memcached on centOS 7 with PHP7

Tags: php7, memcached, php-opcache

I upgraded php7 but when I install 
`yum install php-opcache and php-memcache`, occurs error

```
Error: php70u-common conflicts with php-common-5.6.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How to solve this problem or install via ?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the following two .rpm packages:
[php70-opcache](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/remi-x86_64/php70-php-pecl-memcache-3.0.9-0.7.20161124gitdf7735e.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm.html)
[php70-memcache](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/remi-x86_64/php70-php-pecl-memcache-3.0.9-0.7.20161124gitdf7735e.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm.html)

The installation command is:

```
rpm -ivh <package file>
```